# Unable to view series data while moving navigation in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, asp.net-mvc-5

I am unable to view series data on chart while i have already series data in navigator

see the code

```
 series: {
                data: arry_kwh_2,
                type: 'column',
                color: '#4572A7',
                fillOpacity: 0.05,
                dataGrouping: {
                    smoothed: true
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
```

still i am unable to view the data  [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiWFB.jpg)

I have followed [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/navigator/series-data/) but unable to perform the task

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle showing the problem?  Or include your full config object with some sample data?

Comment: So you are loading different data into navigator as in the working demo of Highstock? Maybe there is a difference in data sets that shows like in the image you have included? Please add a JSFiddle demo with hard-coded data to show the problem.